# Listener in a webapp request / controller

Tags: java, design-patterns, web-applications, concurrency, websocket

I'd like to know which is the best design / class structure for the following situation:

I have a webpage that shows server side events to the end user. The communication between the server and the client (browser) is done through websockets. This allows me to push data to the web.

This server side events are generated by a service. When the request thread begins the flow (the controller) I subscribe to that service. When the service generates an event the "controller" gets notified and sends a websocket push to the browser. The event is shown.

So far so good, but, I have many problems to control the lists of subscribers on the service. I do not know when to unsubscribe because I don't know when the user leaves the page.

The structure I have in mind is:

```
public class Controller{

    WebsocketService websocketService;
    AsyncNotificationsService asyncService;

    public void processRequest(){
          asyncService.subscribe(new Listener(){
               public void do(Obj event){
                      websocketService.notify(process(event));
                      if(condition(event)) unsubscribe(this);
               }
          });
    }
}
```

This code has some flaws:

- Concurrent modifications
- Memory leaks
- Loss of control

I can design the *Controller* and the *AsyncNotificationsService*. What is a correct solution for that?

How would you implement both classes?